# Call form post action after onSubmit print()

Tags: javascript, php, printing, onsubmit

I have a simple

```
<form action="myAction.php" method="POST" onSubmit="print()">
...
</form>
```

I want to print the current page and then the form submit shall call myAction.php.

In chrome it works. In Firefox the action is not called.

Why the print event in firefox does not return true?

Comment: Post the `print()` function aswell.

Comment: Use window.print() it works for me.

Comment: the print() function is the native window.print() . I tried window.print() but it only works in chrome for me

Comment: I think it must have to do something with the print precess, when I click the print cancel button, Firefox makes the action. But when I print it stucks on the same page.